# How can I execute IO commands repeatedly in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, for-loop

I have a function `blabla` in Haskell which takes an Int and returns a string:

```
blabla :: Int -> [Char]
```

I want to run that method repeatedly in a for-loop, something like this:

```
for i := 1 to 25 do begin
    write(i);
    write(": ");
    writeln(blabla(i));
end;
```

Does haskell have a for loop feature?

Comment: So, you want a function of type `[something] -> IO ()`, essentially? That would be `mapM_ print` after `import Control.Monad`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's a [`forM_`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=forM_) function in the `Control.Monad` module which is similar to a for loop in imperative programming languages:

```hs
import Control.Monad (forM_)

blabla :: Int -> String
blabla = show

main = forM_ [1..25] $ \i -> do
    putStr   (show i)
    putStr   ": "
    putStrLn (blabla i)
```

However, I would advise you to stay away from such imperative style code. For example, the same code can be written more succinctly as:

```hs
import Control.Monad (mapM_)

blabla :: Int -> String
blabla = show

main = mapM_ (\i -> putStrLn $ show i ++ ": " ++ blabla i) [1..25]
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: `blabla = (: []) . ("blabla" !!)` ?

Comment: @Mokosha `blabla x = blabla x`.

Comment: "I would advice you to stay away from such imperative style code" - Add an alternative that you consider better and you'll have my vote for this answer.

Comment: I would make this code even less imperative: `putStrLn $ unlines $ map (\x -> concat[show x, ": ", f x]) [1..25]`. Sometimes you need to print a string lazily, line by line, because it is very long or even infinite, but for a short string, it is usually nice to build the entire thing at once and print it.

Comment: @user2407038 Your version is also lazy and works perfectly for an infinite list. BTW both `putStrLn` and `unlines` add a final newline.

Answer (score 7):

Upon drinking a cup of tea I got the best result, I think:

```
blablaResults = map (\x -> show x ++ ":" ++ blabla x) [0..25]

main = putStrLn $ unlines blablaResults
```

Comment: For this specific case, I think this is the best approach because it clearly separates computation and I/O.

Comment: Yes, now you are thinking in a functional style. BTW, you could do truncate this into one line `main = mapM_ (\x -> putStrLn $ show x ++ ": " ++ blabla x) [0..25]`.

Comment: As I mentioned to @user2407038, both `putStrLn` and `unlines` add a final newline.

Answer (score 2):

You're still thinking in a procedural fashion. Try to think in terms of lists, rather than in terms of loops.

Then what you want is a list like this: `[1,f(1),2,f(2),3,f(3)...,n,f(n)]`

This is where `map` enters the picture. If you had a function `f` and wanted to apply it to a list `[1,2,3...,n]`, you use `map f [1..n]`.

What you want is a function that takes a number `i` and applies a function `f` to it,then responds with `[i,f(i)]` or perhaps a tuple `(i,f(i))`.
So you create this function and map it to your list.

And, of course, you need to create that initial list to operate on - that list from [1..n].

Another approach is to use a list comprehension:

```
forloop n = [(x,f x)|x <- [1..n] ]
```

(Note: I have no Haskell compiler with me right now, so I need to verify that last part later. I believe it should work as presented).

Comment: Look at the type of putStrLn and the type of items in your list (which should have 25 items).

Comment: `putStrLn` uses IO, which makes it more complicated. But you don't have to get that into the map - you can create complete string, and then output it using putStrLn later.

Answer (score 0):

I think, I got it by myself:

```
blablaOutput :: [Int] -> IO()
blablaOutput (x:xs) = do 
  putStrLn (blabla x)
  blablaOutput xs
blablaOutput _ = putStrLn "That's all, folks!"  

main = blablaOutput [0..25]
```

Certainly not very functional in means of functional programming, but it works.

Comment: That surely works, and there's nothing wrong with using explicit recursion as you just did. You will find that common patterns like the above one have their place in the standard library. For instance `main = do mapM_ (putStrLn . blabla) [0..25]; putStrLn "That's all, folks!"` is equivalent to the above.